Setting search_kwargs dynamically based on previous chain step
Here's the setup:
My vectorstore (chromadb) has two collections, one with keywords and another with the actual documents for retrieval. Both collections have page number as metadata, and that's how they relate to each other. For example, in the keyword collection I would have a doc like this:
Document(page_content="SomeKeyword", metadata={'pages': '23, 29'})
While in the documents collection I would have:
Document(page_content="Lorem ipsum etc etc etc...", metadata={'page': 23})
Then my chain looks basically like this: first we search the keyword store and return the matches. Then we feed this documents into a function that returns a list of relevant page numbers (a list[int]). Then we want the search on the document store to be filtered by the list of relevant page numbers, so that we improve accuracy and speed.
I can do this just fine if I manually construct this chain (i.e. without LCEL), but if I want to take advantage of LCEL, I can't find a way to dynamically set this filter on the chain. For example:
user_input = {"question": "What is SomeKeyword?"}

keyword_retrieval = RunnableParallel(
  keywords=itemgetter("question") | keywords.as_retriever(
    search_type="similarity_score_threshold",
    search_kwargs={"score_threshold": 0.4}),
  question=itemgetter("question"))

page_nums = RunnableParallel(
  page_nums=itemgetter("keywords") | RunnableLambda(get_page_nums),
  question=itemgetter("question"))

docs_retrieval = RunnableParallel(
  context=itemgetter("question") | docs.as_retriever(
    search_kwargs={"filter": {"page": {"$in": itemgetter("page_nums")}}}),
  question=itemgetter("question"))

chain = keyword_retrieval | page_nums | docs_retrieval | prompt | llm

The above fails with
.venv\Lib\site-packages\chromadb\api\types.py", line 364, in validate_where
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Expected operand value to be an list for operator $in, got operator.itemgetter('page_nums')

I kind of understand why it fails, but I cannot figure out how to work around it. Is there any way to dynamically set search_kwargs based on the output of the previous step of the chain in LCEL?

For anyone having a similar issue in the future, I have managed to make it work with this (unclear whether this is the best solution though):
docs_retrieval = RunnableParallel(
    context=lambda inp: itemgetter("question")
        | docs.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"filter": {"page": {"$in": inp["page_nums"]}}}),
    question=itemgetter("question"),
        )

